# JS Selection sort failing

Tags: javascript

I have this code to do selection sort.

```js
function selectionSort(array) {
    for(let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        let smallest = array[j];
            for(let i = j; i >= 0; i--) {
                if(array[i] > smallest) {
                    let temp1 = array[i];
                    let temp2 = array[j];
    
                    array[i] = temp2;
                    array[j] = temp1;
                }
            }
    }
    return array;
}

selectionSort([8, 5, 2, 9, 5, 6, 3]).forEach(element => {
    console.log(element);
});
```

I have added one test case, that fails. My idea here is that `j` is element selector, like a pointer to it, and next loop iterates backwards checking elements before it, and swapping the smallest element. But it kind of works? Some test cases like `[1, 3, 2]` work just fine, but some like this one does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's fix it. As the algorithm says,

- j is running from the start to end
- i is running from j+1 to the end looking for smallest
- after this, we swap the smallest (at smallest_index) with the original[j]
- advanced to next j

```js
function selectionSort(array) {
  for (let j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
    let smallest = array[j];
    let smallest_index = -1;
    for (let i = j + 1; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] <= smallest) {
        smallest = array[i]
        smallest_index = i;
      }

    }
    let temp1 = array[smallest_index];
    let temp2 = array[j];
    array[smallest_index] = temp2;
    array[j] = temp1;

  }

  return array;
}

console.log("" + selectionSort([8, 5, 2, 9, 5, 6, 3]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [guide to the selection sort algorithum](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selection-sort/).

---

Your outer loop should be tracking the *first unsorted element*. Technically yours is, but you are calling the *first unsorted element* `smallest` which it isn't.

Then your inner loop should be searching for the *smallest unsorted element* and swapping it with the *first unsorted element* from the outer loop. You are swapping **every larger element** (instead of the **single smallest**) element after the one at `i`.

Answer (score 0):

There is something off about your alogithm, it should look something like the below.

```js
function selectionSort(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    let min = i;
    for(var j=i+1;j<array.length;j++){
      if(array[j] < array[min])
        min = j;
    }
    
    const tmp1 = array[min]
    const tmp2 = array[i]
    array[i] = tmp1;
    array[min] = tmp2;
  }
  return array;
}

selectionSort([8, 5, 2, 9, 5, 6, 3]).forEach(element => {
  console.log(element);
});
```